# Microsoft Bot Framework Proactive Message which continues the current dialog

Tags: c#, botframework

There is the concept of proactive messages in the Microsoft bot framework -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

I work with multiple different dialogs in my solution where I store some data in database which is loaded for every turn. Depending on the data from the database the state objects are modified and depending on that, the dialogs continue.

In my case user A starts the dialog, the systems responds with "I put you in a queue" then some time later B starts his dialog and is asked if he should be paired with A. After user B confirms, the dialog from user A should continue.

I can write him a simple message like below, but I don’t know how to simply force a new “turn” for the matching user so the dialog would continue.

```csharp
public class BasicBot : IBot
{
    // some properties

    public BasicBot(CustomBotState botState, BotServices services, UserState userState, ConversationState conversationState, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, EndpointService endpointService)
    {
        // set some properties

        _conversationReferenceAccessor = _botState.CreateProperty<Dictionary<string, ConversationReference>>(nameof(MatchConversationReference));
        _dialogStateAccessor = _conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState));
        _matchStateAccessor = _userState.CreateProperty<MatchState>(nameof(MatchState));

        var appId = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(endpointService.AppId) ? "1" : endpointService.AppId;

        Dialogs = new DialogSet(_dialogStateAccessor);
        Dialogs.Add(new MatchDialog(_matchStateAccessor, loggerFactory, services, appId, _conversationReferenceAccessor));
    }        

    private DialogSet Dialogs { get; set; }

    public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var dialogContext = await Dialogs.CreateContextAsync(turnContext);

        if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            var dialogResult = await dialogContext.ContinueDialogAsync();

            if (!dialogContext.Context.Responded)
            {
                var match = LoadMatchFromDatabase();
                await dialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(MatchDialog), match);
            }
        }

        // save the state of conversation, user, bot
    }
}
```

```csharp
public class MatchDialog : ComponentDialog
{
    // some properties

    public MatchDialog(IStatePropertyAccessor<MatchState> stateAccessor, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, BotServices services, string appId, IStatePropertyAccessor<Dictionary<string, ConversationReference>> _matchConversationPropertyAccessor)
            : base(nameof(MatchDialog))
    {
        // set some properties

        var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
        {
                InitializeStateStepAsync,
                WaitForAnswer,
        };

        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(MatchDialog), waterfallSteps));
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> WaitForAnswer(WaterfallStepContext steps, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var otherUser = await GetOtherUser(steps);
        var conversations = await GetMatchConversion(steps.Context);

        if (conversations.ContainsKey(otherUser.Identifier))
        {
            await steps.Context.Adapter.ContinueConversationAsync(AppId, conversations[otherUser.Identifier],
                   async (turnContext, token) =>
                   {
                       await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Found someone for you");

                   },
                   cancellationToken);
        }
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> InitializeStateStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var state = await StateAccessor.GetAsync(stepContext.Context, () => null);
        var match = stepContext.Options as Match;

        if (state == null)
        {
            await StateAccessor.SetAsync(stepContext.Context, new MatchState() { Match = match });
        }
        else if (state.Match == null || match.Id != state.Match.Id)
        {
            state.Match = match;
        }

        return await stepContext.NextAsync();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: To clarify, UserA starts a dialog and during this dialog is entered in a queue. When UserB is found and can pair with UserA, UserA is notified that UserB was found. You then want the dialog with UserA to continue. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes correct. In my case, user A starts the dialog, the systems responds with "I put you in a queue" then some time later B starts his dialog and is asked if he should be paired with A. After user B confirms, the dialog from user A should continue. -> I updated the description with this short description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of ways you can do this, and it really depends on your code. Basically, in the same place where you send the proactive message that User B has been found, you need to call `dc.ContinueDialogAsync()` or `dc.RepromptDialogAsync()`, as applicable.

That being said, I think the best option would be to split your Dialog. One Dialog gets User A in the queue. Once in, they are no longer in a dialog. Once User B is found, it sends User A the new Dialog.

I've more or less done this with [Sample 16. Proactive Messages](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages) by:

1. Creating the Dialog to be called once User B is found
2. Under `CreateCallback()` (which is where this sample proactively sends a message), I added the following code to the end of that method (for some reason it doesn't want to format as code):

> await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Job {jobInfo.TimeStamp} is complete.");
>
> var dc = await Dialogs.CreateContextAsync(turnContext);
>
> await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(MyDialog));

*Note: To test, I created a Dialog for User A after they "run" a job. The dialog sits there until User B completes the job. A new dialog was started for User A right after.*

For you, this probably looks like:

```
//sample how I write something into the other conversation
var conversations = await GetMatchConversion(steps.Context);
if (conversations.ContainsKey(otherUser.Identifier))
{
    await steps.Context.Adapter.ContinueConversationAsync(AppId, conversations[otherUser.Identifier],
           async (turnContext, token) =>
           {
               // Send the user a proactive confirmation message.
               await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"{currentUser.Display()} I found a matching user...");
               var dc = await Dialogs.CreateContextAsync(turnContext);
               await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(UserFoundDialog));
           },
           cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: I have already two seperate dialogs, a QueueDialog and a MatchDialog. I always thought I need the UserState object for that user to access some state properties, but since you always have the turnContext as a parameter everything should be fine! I will try it out...thanks for your time

Comment: @mdrichardson from where you got the Dialogs in proactive call back? I need to implement this solution in my proactive bot please help.